# Nest can't resolve dependencies within the same module?

Tags: typescript, dependencies, nestjs

I have a backend written in Nest.js. After adding some new services, I get this error during startup:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SomeService1 (+, +, ?, +, +, +, +). Please verify whether [2] argument is available in the current context.
```

- The problem is: argument `[2]` of that service is another provider, located **in the same module**.
- I think there are no circular dependencies in the app.
- I wrote a quick script to generate the dependency graph, and it indeed does not have cycles.
- **But:** if I add a `@Inject(forwardRef(() => SomeService2)` before the mentioned injected argument `[2]`, the app magically starts to work...
- There are no other `forwardRef`s in the codebase.

What can I do now to check the source of the problem? *(simpler than randomly commenting out some deps and see if it works ;))* I thought the only reasons can be:

- circular deps
- using a provider from another module not listed in its `exports:` section
- using a provider not listed in the module's `providers:` section

None of the above are true for my app. What other causes can there be? Unfortunately, I can't publish the sources, but I should be able to provide some details if I know what to look for.

---

The constructor of `SomeService0`:

```
constructor(
    private readonly ...: OtherService1,
    private readonly reporter: EventReporter,
    // @Inject(forwardRef(() => SomeService2))  // works if I uncomment this!
    private readonly ...: SomeService2,
    private readonly ...: SomeService3,
    private readonly ...: EvenOtherService1,
    @Inject(eventBusProviderToken)
    eventBus: EventBus,
) {
```

Declaration of `SomeModule`, with names, changed the same way as in the above constructor:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        OtherModule,
        EvenOtherModule,
        <...more imports>
    ],
    controllers: [
        SomeController,
    ],
    providers: [
        SomeService0,
        SomeService1,
        SomeService2,
        SomeService3,
        SomeService4,
    ],
    exports: [
        SomeService3,
    ],
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question really, but I wonder if you could avoid the problem by passing the instances of the required service into the service method calls.

Comment: Are you able to supply a working example of this issue in a github repo or gist? It sounds like you just actually do have a circular reference

Comment: Your SomeService0 is a big orchestrating service, maybe you just have to simply put it in a new module and declaring the imports there. Nestjs would just resolve the deps in the correct order (SomeModule first, then SomeNewModule which contains only SomeService0). If you can't do that... that would probably mean that there is a cycle somewhere in SomeService0 graph.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Monorepo Architecture.

In my case the problem was the import, which was importing from the module "@company/domain/service" instead of "../../services/service" internally.

To remove a warning from Webstorm "import can be shortened" i had to declare all those services in the same index.ts like `export * from './services/service-name/service-name.service`